# Vim: function to switch to the current QuickFix window and perform a command

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a small script for Vim that, after `:make`, will quickly switch the cursor to current QuickFix window (if it exists), and performs a command in it (namely, it will move the cursor to the last line). This way by default I could see the detailed result of the build command.

I'm trying to register my function in `QuickFixCmdPost`:

```
fu! QfMyFunc()
endfunction

au! QuickFixCmdPost make call QfMyFunc()
```

But I can't find what function should I use to find current QuickFix window, and how I can switch into it. I need to do it, because it seems that even in the handling of `QuickFixCmdPost`, current cursor context is set on the buffer the user was editing before using `:make`.

I can probably enumerate all buffers, but how should I differentiate if current buffer is the QuickFix window and it's located in the current tab?

**Edit**: Thanks to Ingo Karkat, I've managed to write the proper script. It ain't beautiful, but it works!

```
fu! QfScrollToEnd()
    for i in tabpagebuflist()
        if getbufvar(i, "&buftype") == "quickfix"
            :copen
            let l:lines = line("$") " get last line
            call cursor(l:lines, 1) " move the cursor to last line
            :wincmd p
            break
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

au! QuickFixCmdPost make call QfScrollToEnd()
```

Comment: If all you want to do is read the output you may just want `:clist` (`:cl` for short) to just echo out the quickfix results. You can even just list out the last message via `:cl -1`. See `:h :clist` for more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help :copen` provides some hints:

> ```
>       The window will contain a special buffer, with
>       'buftype' equal to "quickfix".  Don't change this!
>       The window will have the w:quickfix_title variable set
>       which will indicate the command that produced the
>       quickfix list.
> ```

So, this is one way:

```
:echo !empty(filter(tabpagebuflist(), 'getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype") ==# "quickfix"'))
```

Once you've determined there is a visible quickfix window, you can just use `:copen` to go to it. Then return to the previous window via `:wincmd p`.